# How we can create a formula for buy n items and get n items free?

Tags: php, math, logic, formula, shopping-cart

I would like to create a formula, here are some examples:

**Buy 2 item get 1 item free**

**Or** 
**Buy 3 item get 2 item free**

**Or** 
**Buy 5 item get 1 item free**

And so on... 

Means, it would be like this **Buy x item and get y item free**

Another example for **buy 3 item and get 1 free**:

1 - 0

2 - 0

3 - 1

4 - 1

5 - 1

6 - 2

7 - 2

8 - 2

9 - 3

**Note**: X and y number could be any thing. Pease let me know if anyone has knowledge.

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about.

Comment: @MBo Suppose I have 3 parameters 
var selectedItem = 3;
var needToBuyItems = 3;
var getFreeItem = 1;
Means you will get 1 item free on purchasing 3 items.
I need an output with free items and non free items.

Comment: OK, it is clear now.  Look at answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use integer division

```
freeItems = getFreeItem * intdiv( selectedItem, needToBuyItems)
```

Comment: I found such [php function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intdiv.php) (I am not familiar with php, so perhaps another integer division approach exists)

Answer (score 0):

for calculate the Buy X Qty Get Y Qty Free then we have to get lowest integer value by rounding down of value of selectedItems divided By needToBuyItems. then multiply that value with freeItems

```
$selectedItem = 5;

$needToBuyItems = 3; // buy 3 items
$getFreeItem = 1; // get 1 free

echo $getFreeItem * floor($selectedItem/$needToBuyItems);
```

**-: Output :-**

1. selectedItem = 1 then output of freeItem = 0
2. selectedItem = 3 then output of freeItem = 1
3. selectedItem = 5 then output of freeItem = 1
4. selectedItem = 6 then output of freeItem = 2
5. selectedItem = 7 then output of freeItem = 2
6. selectedItem = 9 then output of freeItem = 3